# facebook thumbnail only gives 3 image choices

Tags: facebook

I am having issues with thumbnail preview of images show up on facebook when I post a link.  I have a photography blog with lots of images, but only 3 random photos are showing up.  My website is htttp://limonphotography.com/blog/.  I did not have this issue before, and I was able to choose from almost all the images before.  I looked through the stackoverflow database and didn't find any solution to this.  I am using the Thesis theme for the blog with the following plugins active: 
 - Askimet
 - All in One SEO
 - Disqus comment system
 - Facebook AWD all in one
 - Facebook comments
 - Google Analytics
 - Google XML
 - Pinetrest Pin it button lite
 - Spam free wordpress
 - Wordpress importer

I tried to run my site link through debugger and I get the following 
critical error:

> > Could Not Follow Redirect Path:   Using data from http://limonphotography.com/blog/ because there was an error following the redirect path.

Errors that must be fixed:

> > Circular Redirect Path:   Circular redirect path detected (see 'Redirect Path' section for details).
> >     Could Not Follow Redirect:  URL requested a HTTP redirect, but it could not be followed.

Also having some OG errors, but these don't show up if I use my link with a / in the debugger.

I am not tech-savy at all, so I'm not sure if this is because of a plugin that's installed, redirection issues, the thesis theme, or something different altogether.

Comment: 1. Either you present images you want to be used as thumbnails explicitly via _correct_ Open Graph meta tags, or Facebook might choose images randomly using criteria you can hardly influence; 2. I think Facebook has limited the number of thumbnails shown to the user to chose from when sharing to a maximum of three some while ago, no matter whether a page has more images included or even more images are explicitly provided via `og:image` tags.

Comment: Facebook set limits on the image choices?  This is such a pointless limitation.  Just a month ago you had the ability to choose from all the images displayed on the first page.  Is the open graph meta tags implemented through facebook's debug, or website meta tags?  And also, does that set the same image for all future links, or just that specific post?

Comment: You seem to be quite unfamiliar with how Open Graph pages work, so please read up on it in the docs a bit: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/creating-object-types/#properties